# Mysql average of data not further than 3 minutes apart

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am trying to create a query that averages datarows that are no more than 3 minutes apart. Of course it is not necessary like in the image that the rows are 2 seconds apart.

So how could I select the rows in such a period and get the average of for example "engine_load" in that period.

[image]

According to the example in the image I would need the data from ids 19428-19431 and the data from 19423-19427 as average. If there would be a row with datetime 2021-04-27 12:25:15 for example, this row would be the only row in his "period" because there aren't any other rows closer than 3 minutes.

Comment: What happens if the data could match multiple groups? e.g. Row 1 = 12:00, row 2 = 12:02, row 3 = 12:04. Would row 2 be included with row 1, row 3, both, or either?

Comment: Normally there wouldn't be data that could match multiple groups.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

If you are defining *breaks* as three minutes, then you can use `lag()` and then a cumulative sum to define the groups:

```
select min(id), max(id), min(datetime), max(datetime),
       avg(engine_load)
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_datetime > datetime - interval 3 minute then 0 else 1 end) over (order by datetime) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(datetime) over (order by datetime) as prev_datetime
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp;
```

Comment: Thanks already, but it seems like the MySQL version i'm using isn't supporting lag(), as it gives me a syntax error. As I have no control over the server I also can't update it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're unable to use `lag` like in Gordon Linoff's excellent answer and you confirmed in the comments that it's not possible for groups to overlap, you could probably try something like the following:

```
SELECT mindatetime, MAX(datetime) maxdatetime, avg(engine_load)
FROM
(
 SELECT (SELECT MIN(m2.datetime) FROM mytable m2 WHERE m2.datetime > DATE_SUB(m1.datetime, INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)) mindatetime, m1.datetime, m1.engine_load
 FROM mytable m1
) mt
GROUP BY mindatetime
```

The inner query just gets each row, plus the minimum row that has a date time within 3 minutes of that row. The outer query groups by that minimum date time and does the average.

This is really dependent on the fact that there are no overlaps and will not give you the expected result otherwise. You will also want to confirm whether `>` is more appropriate than `>=` (whether it is possible for rows to be exactly 3 minutes apart and how that should work).

Comment: Thank you for your explaination. Could be that i misunderstood the "group" from your comment. So if I got it right now, it would definetly be included in both groups. Sorry for the confusion. Your piece of code gives me many rows even though they are within 3 mins: https://i.imgur.com/xocJGy3.png